# Angular 1.x ES6 services $http undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I use AngularJS with ES6, and when i call **register** function from my service, i have an error:

```
this.$http is undefined
```

My service:

```
export default class AccountService {
  /* @ngInject */
  contructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
  }

  register(account) {
    return this.$http.post('/api/accounts/register', account).then(result => result.data);
  }
}

AccountService.$inject = ['$http'];
```

Register my service:

```
import AccountService from './services/accounts.service';
angular.module('app', [...])
  /* ... */
  .service('accountService', AccountService)
```

In my controller:

```
export class RegisterController {
  /* @ngInject */
  constructor(accountService) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
  }

  register(account) {
    this.accountService.register(account);
  }
}
```

I use generator : https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `constructor` as `contructor`. It never gets called, therefore doesn't assign `this.$http`.

Comment: oh my god, 2 days for that :(.